# How to correctly insert into a M..N table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple setup with 3 Tables: `Role`, `Permission` and `RolePermission`.

```
Role:            | Permission:            | RolePermission:
ID    SysName    | ID    SysName          | Role    Permission
--    -------    | --    -------          | ----    ----------
 1    Admin      |  1    DoUserThings     |    1    1
 2    User       |  2    DoAdminThings    |    1    2
                 |  3    HackTheGibson    |    1    3
                                          |    2    1
```

The idea is that Roles and Permissions exist separately, and the table "RolePermission" assigns which Roles have which Permissions.

In this example, Admins have all the Permissions and Users have the `DoUserThings` permission.

However, I am unsure how to correctly write an INSERT statement. I wrote one which queries both the `Role` and `Permission` table, but it doesn't seem the most performant. I considered a JOIN statement, although I am unsure what to join on what.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
INSERT INTO RolePermission (Role, Permission)
SELECT Role.ID, Permission.ID
FROM Role, Permission
WHERE
    Role.SysName == 'Admin'
    AND
    Permission.SysName == 'DoUserThings';
```

This would insert `1, 2` into the `RolePermission` table.

---

Note: I'm currently using SQLite for testing, but would like to be compatible with MySQL and/or PostgreSQL.

Comment: Your query looks fine. I can't imagine you're doing this very often so why does performance matter?

Comment: Why use SQLite for testing, when you're going to Postgresql or MySQL? They are both available at no cost.

Comment: `FROM Role, Permission` <- Note that this way to join tables is deprecated since about 25 years

Comment: @Nick In a way, it's also a learning experience. I might have a similar setup, but with more data in the future, and then I would have to worry about performance. Hence why I asked for the "correct" way to do things.

Comment: @jarlh Because I like to not have to worry about setting up a server if I am just working on a small project. SQLite works fine for this purpose.

Comment: @Cid Yes, I am aware. Hence my question

Comment: @MechMK1 then Gordon's answer is what you are looking for

Comment: @Cid I already upvoted it. I have to wait for the cooldown to wear off before being able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is fine, although I might be inclined to phrase it as:

```
INSERT INTO RolePermission (Role, Permission)
    SELECT r.ID, p.ID
    FROM Role r JOIN
         Permission p
         ON r.SysName = 'Admin' AND
            p.SysName = 'DoUserThings';
```

From a performance perspective, it doesn't really matter how you phrase the logic.  If you care about performance, then add indexes on `Role(SysName, Id)` and `Permission(SysName, Id)`.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer in 2 minutes, as soon as it's possible. One minor note: What's with the keywords at the end of the lines? I've never seen this style before

Comment: @MechMK1 . . . I put operators at the end of lines -- they are intentionally dangling so if the next line is missing, then the query fails when compiling.  `JOIN` is an operator that connects two tables.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of join's purpose. I like the idea of putting such a failsafe in the code. I guess I'll start copying your style now